# Attach Entity with parameter value null using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

So, I'm trying to update rows where LOGIN IS NULL and ID = 1. If there are no rows with these parameters then add new row. I use attach to make that in 1-2 queries so I'm trying to avoid SELECT first and then update.

Problem in NULL value. EF simply ignores LOGIN since it has null value, however I need to find only rows where LOGIN IS NULL. Can I solve that problem without additional SELECT query?

My code:

```
        using (var db = new EntityContext())
        {
            var ent = new Entity { ID = 1, LOGIN = null };
            db.Entities.Attach(ent);
            ent.LOGIN = "Whatever";
            ent.EMAIL = "Whatever";
            int count = db.SaveChanges();
            if (count == 0)
            {
                var clone_ent = new Entity { LOGIN = "Whatever", PASS = "Whatever" };
                db.Entities.Add(clone_ent);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

SQL analog:

```
UPDATE Entities SET LOGIN = @LOGIN, EMAIL = @EMAIL
WHERE ID = 1 AND LOGIN IS NULL
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT INTO Entities (LOGIN, EMAIL)
    VALUES @LOGIN, @EMAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to include a WHERE condition into UPDATE statements in entity framework so you will have to select, then update or insert, e.g.:

```
using (var db = new EntityContext())
{
    var ent = db.Entities.Where(x => x.ID == 1 && x.LOGIN == null).FirstOrDefault(); 
    if (ent != null)
    {
        ent.LOGIN = "Whatever";
        ent.EMAIL = "Whatever";
    }
    else
    {
        db.Entities.Add(ent);
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```